# Are these quotes by Malcom X, Albert Einstein, Nelson Mandela and Mahatma Gandhi about the Israeli–Palestinian conflict correct?

Tags: quotes, mahatma-gandhi, palestine

I've seen this image on Facebook, often these image macros are just made up, or misattributed quotes, what about in this case?

Image content:

> #Free Palestine

> The Zionist argument to justify Israel's present occupation of Arab Palestine has no intelligent or legal basis in history... not even in their own religion. - Malcom X

> It would be my greatest sadness to see Zionists (Jews) do to Palestinian Arabs much of what Nazis did to Jews - Albert Einstein

> We know too well that our freedom is incomplete without the freedom of the Palestinians. - Nelson Mandela

> Palestine belongs to the Arabs in the same sense that England belongs to the English or France to the French. It is wrong and inhuman to impose the Jews on the the Arabs. - Mahatma Ghandi

[image: quotes about notable people speaking to palestine]

Comment: It's worth noting that Malcolm X later supported Israel (*The Autobiography of Malcolm X*) and that Nelson Mandela praised Zionism and always supported a 2 state solution, stating that Palestine and Israel both had the right to exist and to self-determination.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

**MALCOLM X**

> In short the zionist argument to justify Israel's present occupation
>   of Arab Palestine has no intelligent or legal basis in history.

Status: **correct**. This quote is extracted from *"ZIONIST LOGIC By Malcolm X Shabazz"*.<sup>(1)</sup>

**ALBERT EINSTEIN**

> It would be my greatest sadness to see Zionists do to Palestinian
>   Arabs much of what Nazis did to Jews.

Status: **incorrect**. There is no recorded evidence that Einstein said this sentence - without forgetting also that Einstein  was a Cultural Zionist who supported the idea of a Jewish homeland <sup>(4)</sup> and he actually got an offer to be the president of Israel in 1952. <sup>(5)</sup> .

Skepticaesoterica's [opinion](http://skepticaesoterica.com/debunking-fake-albert-einstein-quotes/),

> The motivation for this fake quote should be apparent. It would be
>   beneficial to pro-Palestinian activists to show that a paragon of
>   wisdom, and a Jew himself no less, was also pro-Palestinian and/or
>   anti-Israel.

**NELSON MANDELA**

> We know too well that our freedom is incomplete without the freedom of
>   the Palestinians.

Status: **correct**. Extracted from Mandela's speech at the International Day of Solidarity with the Palestinian People<sup>(2)</sup>.

Full quote:

> When in 1977, the United Nations passed the resolution inaugurating
>   the International Day of Solidarity with the Palestinian people, it
>   was asserting the recognition that injustice and gross human rights
>   violations were being perpetrated in Palestine. In the same period,
>   the UN took a strong stand against apartheid; and over the years, an
>   international consensus was built, which helped to bring an end to
>   this iniquitous system. But we know too well that our freedom is
>   incomplete without the freedom of the Palestinians; without the
>   resolution of conflicts in East Timor, the Sudan and other parts of
>   the world.

**MAHATMA GANDHI**

> Palestine belongs to the Arabs in the same sense that England belongs
>   to the English or France to the French. It is wrong and in-human to
>   impose the Jews on the Arabs.

Status: **correct**.  <sup>(3)</sup>

<sup>(1) [ZIONIST LOGIC](http://law.wustl.edu/staff/taylor/protest/aaprp3.htm) By Malcolm X Shabazz (Edited and Reprinted From The Egyptian Gazette - Sept. 17, 1964)</sup>

<sup>(2) [Address at The International Day of Solidarity with the Palestinian People](http://www.anc.org.za/show.php?id=3384) Nelson Mandela. 4 December 1997.</sup>

<sup>(3) Gandhi's Collected Works, Vol 74 (1938)</sup>

<sup>(4)  Stachel, John (2001-12-10). Einstein from 'B' to 'Z'. Birkhäuser Boston. p. 70. ISBN 0-8176-4143-2.</sup>

<sup>(5)  "ISRAEL: Einstein Declines". Time magazine. 1 December 1952. Retrieved 31 March 2010.</sup>

Comment: Pretty good answer, but regarding Einstein, the opinions of a blogger to the possible motivation of whoever mis-attributed the quote isn't really proof of anything. I've seen this quote thousands of times, and you should never forget [Hanlon's razor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hanlon%27s_razor).

Comment: Regarding Einstein, it is not sure whether he was a "huge" supporter of Zionism:
http://dissidentvoice.org/2010/01/einstein-on-palestine-and-zionism/

Comment: @MrLore The phenomenon of attributing quotes to famous people who never said the words is well known (e.g., [1](http://online.wsj.com/news/articles/SB10001424127887323717004578155302814623978), [2](http://www.npr.org/templates/transcript/transcript.php?storyId=241295755), [3](http://magazine.good.is/articles/if-mark-twain-said-it-he-probably-didnt)). While such misattributions aren't necessarily malicious *per se*, they're also not necessarily incompetence.

Comment: @georgechalhoub Actually, I think it is plausible that Einstein said something along those lines: [Letter to the New York Times 1948 - signed by Albert Einstein](https://archive.org/details/AlbertEinsteinLetterToTheNewYorkTimes.December41948)

Comment: Just because Einstein was a supporter of Zionism to a degree does not mean that he could not be disappointed with the actions of some Zionists.

Comment: Gandhi was talking with a quite different historical context as background, some time before the holocaust. He surely meant: Palestine does not belong to the English.

Comment: And let's not forget that both Mandela and Malcolm X are viewed as terrorists by many.

Comment: Is it just me or does it sound like Gandhi is saying two different things: "It is wrong and in-human to impose the Jews on the Arabs." I thought he was going with saying that the Palestenians have as much right to Palestine as the Jews to Israel. Am I wrong?

Comment: Malcom X was (by that point) a Sunni Muslim.  Are we supposed to be _surprised_ that he spoke out against an Israeli state?

Comment: @georgechalhoub - The implied statement behind the original image is "hey, these are all famous civil-rights people who had something to say in support of the Palestinians/against the Israelis, we should think like this too.", but which didn't account for, hmm, "default bias" (or potentially any other context-relevant information).  Merely verifying the quote is correct says nothing about if it is (possibly) being misapplied, or if some other context should disqualify it for the use at hand.

Comment: I'm downvoting this answer for the Einstein bit. You add 'Einstein was a Cultural Zionist' stating that he would not stand by the quote. Just because you found no literal source, does not give you the right to insinuate this. It correlates extremely closely with his stance on nationalism, and the letter to the NYT quoted earlier. You abuse Einstein by misrepresenting him. Just say the quote is false, and link to his stance on nationalism. No need to get all 'ohhh how convenient for the Zionists' on here.

Comment: The fact that he supported a homeland for jews does not make him a supporter of oppression of Arabs. You don't say there's no source - you actively are trying to persuade the reader into believing Einstein would not agree with the sentence. That is disgusting. Simply state 'No, there is no source for his quote. He was a pacifist and wrote a letter in the NYT condemning nationalist Israeli party members. However, he was supportive of an Israeli state.' and you'd have my upvote for a well-researched answer, instead of my contempt for misrepresenting one of the greatest men in history.

Comment: The Einstein quote is eminently plausible and consistent with Einstein's post-war views. It is important to understand that the meaning of Zionism had shifted enormously between the beginning of the century and the 1950s. Einstein was strongly opposed to Begin and views his zionism as fascist. He was not shy to express his opinion. The quote could plausibly be a translation of an interview with the foreign press in one of the many languages he spoke.

Comment: @Spork the NYT letter seems to be opposing one party, not even the one leading the Israeli government at that time. I don't see any relationship to the Palestinian conflict as a whole